# Как узнать redirect если в header адрес указан неправильно?

Tags: java

Используя `HttpURLConnection` запрашиваю у страницы с кодом 301 `getHeaderField("Location")`. В header адрес переадресации указан неправильно. Страница указывает сама на себя. Однако, обращаясь к узлу через браузер происходит перенаправление. Как программно узнать адрес переадресации, если Location указан неправильно? Ст. http: // fe.sales.parks.org.il

Comment: Это переадресация со сменой протокола: http -> https. Можно попробовать обратиться сразу к `https://`, либо аккуратнее обращаться с протоколами.

Comment: @BccHnw Если запрашивать header по протоколу https, то там вообще нет поля "Location". Непонятно каким образом происходит переадресация? По адресу `https` страница со скриптом переадресации. Content-Length: 3841. Чтобы найти куда идёт перенаправление, мне получается нужно сначала скачать страницу, распарсить скрипт, и только так можно узнать конечный адрес?